# Resource Creation Breaks Stack Deployment

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

So I am trying to do a clean deploy of all the infrastructure needed to use AWS Config and about 14 managed rules. The issue I'm having comes up when AWS Config is already enabled in the specific account as it does not like that I am trying to redeploy the necessary Infra (Config Recorder and Config Delivery Channel). I am trying to set up my logic to immediately try to just deploy the rules if it gets an error of existing infrastructure.
Here is my code:

```
 import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core')
import lambda = require('@aws-cdk/aws-lambda');
import path = require('path')
import s3 = require('@aws-cdk/aws-s3');
import iam = require('@aws-cdk/aws-iam');
import config = require('@aws-cdk/aws-config');
import { ManagedRule } from '@aws-cdk/aws-config';
import events = require('@aws-cdk/aws-events');
import targets = require('@aws-cdk/aws-events-targets');
import { Arn, Aws } from '@aws-cdk/core';
import core = require('@aws-cdk/core')
import { allowedNodeEnvironmentFlags, env } from 'process';
import { SnsTopic } from '@aws-cdk/aws-events-targets';
import * as deliveryChannelConfigStack from '../lib/deliveryChannelConfig';




export class fullConfigStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
      super(scope, id, props);
      const globalConfigRole = new iam.Role(this, 'globalConfigRole', {
        assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('config.amazonaws.com'),   // required
    });

   
    globalConfigRole.addManagedPolicy(iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('service-role/AWSConfig'));
    globalConfigRole.addManagedPolicy(iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('ReadOnlyAccess'));
    
      const globalConfigRecorder = new config.CfnConfigurationRecorder(this, 'globalConfigRecorder',{
        roleArn: globalConfigRole.roleArn,    
        name: 'globalConfigRecorder',
        recordingGroup: {
          allSupported: true,
          includeGlobalResourceTypes: true
      }
    });
    const globalConfigBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'globalConfigBucket',{
        accessControl: s3.BucketAccessControl.LOG_DELIVERY_WRITE
      });
    const cisConfigDeliveryChannel = new config.CfnDeliveryChannel(this,'cisConfigDeliveryChannel',{
        s3BucketName: globalConfigBucket.bucketName,
        configSnapshotDeliveryProperties: {
            deliveryFrequency: 'TwentyFour_Hours'
        }
    });
    const generalConfigRole = new iam.Role(this,  'generalConfigRole',{
        assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('config.amazonaws.com')
      });

      const cloudTrailEnabledRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'cloudTrailEnabledRule', {
        identifier: 'CLOUD_TRAIL_ENABLED'
      });
     
      const userGroupMembershipRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'userGroupMembershipRule',{
        identifier: 'IAM_USER_GROUP_MEMBERSHIP_CHECK'
      });


      const rootAccountMfaEnabledRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'rootAccountMfaEnabledRule',{
        identifier: 'ROOT_ACCOUNT_MFA_ENABLED'
      });
      const accessKeysRotatedRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'accessKeysRotatedRule',{
        identifier:'ACCESS_KEYS_ROTATED',
        inputParameters: {
          maxAccessKeyAge: 90 //rule triggers off of config change and keys must be rotated within 100 days
        }
      });
      const  iamPasswordPolicyRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'iamPasswordPolicyRule',{
        identifier: 'IAM_PASSWORD_POLICY',
        inputParameters: {
            RequireUppercaseCharacters: true, 
            RequireLowercaseCharacters: true,        
            RequireSymbols: true, 
            RequireNumbers: true, 
            MinimumPasswordLength: 14, 
            PasswordReusePrevention: 24, 
            MaxPasswordAge: 90
         
        }
      });
      const cloudTrailEncryptionRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'cloudTrailEncryptionRule' ,{
        identifier:'CLOUD_TRAIL_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED',

      });
      const defaultSecurityGroupEniRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'defaultSecurityGroupEniRule',{
        identifier:'EC2_SECURITY_GROUP_ATTACHED_TO_ENI'
      });

      const ebsVolumeEncryption = new ManagedRule(this, 'ebsVolumeEncryption',{
        identifier:'EC2_EBS_ENCRYPTION_BY_DEFAULT'
      });
      const rdsStorageEncryptionRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'rdsStorageEncryptionRule',{
        identifier: 'RDS_STORAGE_ENCRYPTED'
        //This may need the arn of the kms key used for encryption
      });

      const s3ConfigLoggingEnabledBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 's3ConfigLoggingEnabledBucket',{
        accessControl: s3.BucketAccessControl.LOG_DELIVERY_WRITE
      }); 


      const s3BucketLoggingEnabledRule = new ManagedRule(this, 's3BucketLoggingEnabledRule',{
        identifier: 'S3_BUCKET_LOGGING_ENABLED',
        // inputParameters: {
        //   targetBucket:  s3ConfigLoggingEnabledBucket,
        });

      const s3BucketServerSideEncryptionRule = new ManagedRule(this, 's3BucketServerSideEncryptionRule',{
        identifier:'S3_BUCKET_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED'
      });

        const vpcFlowLogsEnabledRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'vpcFlowLogsEnabledRule',{
        identifier:'VPC_FLOW_LOGS_ENABLED',
        inputParameters: {
          trafficType:'ALL' //vpcs must track all traffic (ALLOW and DENY) with this rule
        }
      });

      const vpcDefaultSecurityGroupRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'vpcDefaultSecurityGroupRule',{
        identifier:'VPC_DEFAULT_SECURITY_GROUP_CLOSED'
      });

      const mfaEnabledForConsoleAccessRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'mfaEnabledForConsoleAccessRule',{
        identifier: 'MFA_ENABLED_FOR_IAM_CONSOLE_ACCESS'
      });

      const rdsMultiAvailZoneRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'rdsMultiAvailZoneRule',{
        identifier:'RDS_MULTI_AZ_SUPPORT'
      });

      const iamUserUnusedCredentialsRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'iamUserUnusedCredentialsRule',{
        identifier: 'IAM_USER_UNUSED_CREDENTIALS_CHECK',
        inputParameters: {
          maxCredentialUsageAge: 90
        }
      });
```

As you see in the code I am creating a role a config recorder, configBucket,delivery channel, and about 14 managed rules. Now if I split this code into 2 different stacks, one being just the infra and one being the rules. The rules on their own deploy perfectly fine regardless if they are already deployed. But, if I try to deploy the entire thing, I get this error:

```
You must create a configuration recorder before you can create or update a Config rule. (Service: AmazonConfig; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NoAvailableConfigurationRecorderException; Request ID: a2951019-1
d7b-44a9-8df2-83e6a4a0e229; Proxy: null)
```

The reason I think I am getting this is because the recorder takes longer to deploy and therefore the program tries to move on to the rules and errors out. My question is this, is there a way that I can have the program wait until the recorder and delivery channel are done? Or, can I do this in another stack and reference the stack with IF, ELSE logic or something similar? Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/core-readme.html#construct-dependencies):

> Sometimes AWS resources depend on other resources, and the creation of one resource must be completed before the next one can be started.

> If you need to add an ordering dependency that is not automatically inferred, you do so by adding a dependency relationship using constructA.node.addDependency(constructB).

You can add additional dependencies between resources like so:

```
globalConfigRole.node.addDependency(globalConfigRecorder)
```